# What exactly is CLEARANCE in CSS

Tags: css, css-float, margin

So, I have taken to reading the CSS specification to better understand how to use style properties and attributes in my code. Currently on Box model- Collapsing Margins, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margin , and I came across this line in the spec.

> If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are
>   adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of
>   following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with
>   the bottom margin of the parent block

Anyone care to explain what the above really means please? Also shine more light on clearance as used above please. would definitely appreciate your input here.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe look at it like this.

Suppose you have a left floated element. Lets call it block F. That block is taken out of the flow by the float, so the next block element (assume that it's not floated, and call that block B) starts at exactly the same place horizontally and vertically as block F. When text is placed in block B, it starts to fill up block B, but the text won't overlap with block F. That's what floats do.

Suppose too that there is a another block element, also not floated and call that block C. (This is going to be our important one). Block C will be placed immediately below block B. This, depending on the relative heights of blocks F and B might start above the bottom of Block F or below it.

**-- Stop here and make sure you've got the two possible pictures of the three blocks F, B, C  clear in your mind --**

Now, suppose we apply `clear:left` to block C. If block C starts below the bottom of block F then the `clear:left` has no effect and there is no clearance.

If block C starts above the bottom of block F, then block C is moved down until its start is no longer above the bottom of block F. The distance it is moved is called the **clearance**.

[The description above is a bit glossed over. Is the "start" of a block the inner or outer edge of the margin box, border box, padding box, or content box? Similarly for "top" and "bottom". We don't need to worry about this here, but the CSS spec nails it all down.]

Once clearance or not has been established, then the behaviour of what can happen with margin collapsing can be applied mechanically.

So, to answer your comment questions, clearance can only happen when a clear property other than "none" is applied, but that's not sufficient, the block must actually be moved down. Thus the quoted margin collapsing rule only applies to block C if block C is actually moved down by the `clear:left` rule.

Finally, note that for historical reasons, there are situations where a clear rule can be applied indirectly via an HTML attribute, rather than directly in CSS.

Comment: Hm. . . could you please provide an illustration of what you have up there in a JSFiddle-hosted example please? Gosh . . . I am scratching my head here trying to visualize this.

Comment: OK. Try this. In [Case one](http://jsfiddle.net/MDjBB/3/) the height of the block B is less than that of F. The clearance is the vertical gap between the green box and the blue box. In [Case two](http://jsfiddle.net/MDjBB/2/) the height of block B is greater than that of F. There is no vertical gap between the green and the blue box, so there is no clearance.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I commend your desire to want to understand CSS properly. But it will make your head spin sometimes.

Comment: Based on what you have in your example case A, are you saying that F(a floated block), and C (a left-cleared block),both out-of-flow, have adjoining margins?

Comment: F is floated, C is cleared. Yes. But C is in-flow. I haven't depicted any margins, but the rule about the adjoining margins would only apply to block C in case one, because only it has clearance. Other collapsing margin rules may apply that do not relate to clearance.

Comment: How can C be in-flow when it obvious shifted up with the left-clearing?

Comment: Shifted down. In-flow has nothing to do with its shift. It flows on from block B (before it is shifted) and subsequent elements flow on after it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was a test, but the exact instance of the word “clearance” that you quoted was actually linked to the description/definition for the purposes of that very spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#clearance

> Values other than 'none' potentially introduce clearance. Clearance inhibits margin collapsing and acts as spacing above the margin-top of an element. It is used to push the element vertically past the float.

Comment: I read that bit of information of course, but it did not really give me a clear picture of what clearance is and where it comes from. For instance, if I do not specify CLEAR value, is it still possible to get clearance between my boxes? Is avoiding the use of CLEAR a sure way of avoiding CLEARANCE issues when collapsing margins?